# Error "address of stack memory associated with local variable 'processList' returned" when trying to return int array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, int

I have a function that should create an array with unique numbers from another array that has a lot of unsorted repeated numbers, and then return it. However I get an error that I can't understand, tried googling an no relevant results :(

```
int *findProcessList(int processIdentifier[])
{
    int processList[50]; //Number of unique processes
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
        if(processList[j] == processIdentifier[i])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            processList[j] = processIdentifier[i];
        }

    }
}
return processList;
```

I get an error "address of stack memory associated with local variable
      'processList' returned"

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Not only that, but you are accessing uninitialized data.  Consider this line `if (processList[j] == processIdentifier[i])` on the first time through the loops (when i and j are both 0), what is in `processList[0]`?  Answer: garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Answer these questions: What happens to a local variable if you return from the function where it is defined? What happens to the address of a local variable if you return from the function where it is defined? What happens to the address of the local array "processList" when you return from the function where it is defined?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answers to these questions, maybe thats the problem...